# How to batch create N number of servers in Compute Engine via Google Cloud Client?

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I am currently using the Java Google Cloud Client for Compute Engine. I am interested if it is possible to "batch" create N number of servers for Compute Engine via the Google Cloud Client API? (note: I'd like to use an API instead of the gcloud command line). I've looked through documentation and there doesn't seem to be an API to create N servers in parallel. This capability exists for AWS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean create N virtual machines with 1 HTTP request?

Comment: Yes correct and for VMs to be created in parallel

Comment: You can send n requests in parallel, but not in a single request.

Comment: :( I see. Thanks. By the way, do you know if there is an API in the client to generate or pass by parameter an SSH key pair to be used by the newly created instance? Can't seem to find any SSH API in the Google client.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys

Comment: Thanks I saw that. It looks like it's easily done using the gcloud command line tool, but I'd prefer to use a library with an API. I'm using the Java google cloud client but there doesn't seem to be any APIs for handling/managing SSH keys for instances. Perhaps it is because it is still in "alpha".

Comment: gcloud command is just a wrapper of REST API, see the "API" tab next to "GLOUD".